# How to calculate the percent of total income out of goal income? PHP

Tags: php, formula

I've added a progress bar on my payment page and I'd like it to show our members how much we've made and how much left.

Now, I can do all that. All I need help is the formula for the total money made by how much left.

Other information you may need. MY database stores the price as 2 decimal places. Using `number_format($var, 2);`

I need the percent so i can print it on progress bars attribute to display the actual bar (Bootstrap bar).

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide total income out of goal income, and multiply it by 100:

```
$percentage = ($total / $goal) * 100;
```

Comment: Good one buddy. My maths sucks. I should have known.

Answer (score 0):

```
 number_format(($total_made/$total_needed),2)*100;
```

will give you the decimal ratio that the need.